# Spring Batch to read multiple csv and xls file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to create spring batch job which will read files from a network location and those files can be of csv format or xls/xlsx format.

Since file format is different, I have used flatfileItemReader and PoiItemReader, provided by spring-batch-excel.

After reading those files, I need to update DB tables.

**I am unable to decide how should I approach for this logic where based on file format different reader need to be called.**

First I thought, I will create a step which will read a file from that location and then will implement JobExecutionDecider which will check for file extension and will call respective fileReader. However, I am unable to understand how will I get response of step i.e. file object

```
public class FileReaderDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether I am thinking in right direction. Any suggestion to select reader based on file format will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Or you could simply create two jobs using the same Processor and Writer?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I thought of this also but as I need to get my design approved, how will I justify that I need to create two jobs to handle different reader when their end goal is same? As I am new to spring batch, not sure limitation in spring batch or in my outlook.

Comment: I'm using Spring Batch for many years and that's the approach I would choose. You are reusing Processor and Writer so this is ok.